# Error: setlocale() failed when I run crunch in ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, kali

I installed crunch in my ubuntu, and I follow the steps at http://surfnetz.blogspot.com/2015/06/install-crunch-on-ubuntu.html

Then I have installed crunch, but once I run crunch, it gets error

```
$crunch
Error: setlocale() failed
```

So how can I fix it？

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I think it is because your os doesn't know your locale.
Just add

```
# Setting for the new UTF-8 terminal support in Lion
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

to your .bashrc and it worked for me.